# Show that $\lim_{r \to 0}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(r e^{i \varphi})d\varphi = 2 \pi f(0) $

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, continuity

I need to show that $\lim_{r \to 0} \int_{0}^{2 \pi}f(r e^{i \varphi})d \varphi = 2 \pi f(0)$ if $f$ is continuous on a neighborhood of $z = 0$.

I was given the following hint: Write $\int_{0}^{2 \pi} f(r e^{i \varphi})d \varphi = \int_{0}^{2\pi}f(0) d\varphi + \int_{0}^{2\pi}(f(re^{i \varphi}) - f(0))d \varphi$. Use the $Ml$-inequality to show that the latter integral $\to 0$.

The $Ml$-inequality refers to the following:

> If $f$ is integrable along $\gamma$, $|f(z)|\leq M$ for all $z \in \gamma$, and $l$ is the length of $\gamma$, then $\displaystyle \left\vert \int_{\gamma}f(z)dz \right\vert \leq Ml$.

So, in order to apply this hint, I need to show that $|\int_{0}^{2 \pi}(f(re^{i \varphi})-f(0))d\varphi| \leq M * 2\pi$, but how do I find an $M$ such that $f(re^{i \varphi })-f(0) \leq M$? And even then, how will that inequality show that that integral goes to $0$?

Please note that I am not supposed to know Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem or any similar theorems, so answers using such theorems will not be helpful.

Comment: Assume without loss of generality that $f(0) = 0$ and apply the inequality to the circle centered at $0$ with radius $r$. There's really not much else to do after the hint.

Comment: $f(z)$ is continuous at $0$... all you'll need is $\max_{|z|=r} |f(z)-f(0)|  \to 0$ when $r \to 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous on a neighborhood of zero, given $\delta>0$, there exists $R>0$ such that $|f(re^{i \varphi})-f(0)|\le \delta$ for $r\in[0,R)$ and $\varphi\in\mathbb R$. Hence,
$$
\left\lvert\int_{0}^{2 \pi}(f(re^{i \varphi})-f(0))d\varphi\right| <2\pi\delta
$$
and
$$
\limsup_{r\to0}\left\lvert\int_{0}^{2 \pi}(f(re^{i \varphi})-f(0))d\varphi\right| \le2\pi\delta.
$$
Now let $\delta\to0$ to conclude that
$$
\limsup_{r\to0}\left\lvert\int_{0}^{2 \pi}(f(re^{i \varphi})-f(0))d\varphi\right|=0,
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\lim_{r\to0}\int_{0}^{2 \pi}(f(re^{i \varphi})-f(0))d\varphi=0.
$$

Added: If you want to avoid $\limsup$, write instead
$$
\left\lvert\int_{0}^{2 \pi}(f(re^{i \varphi})-f(0))d\varphi\right|\le2\pi\max_{|z|\le r}|f(z)-f(0)|\to0
$$
when $r\to0$.

Comment: now is the reason for the usage of the $\lim \sup$ related to the hint that user1952009 gave above? I know what a $\lim \sup$ is, but I know a lot of people in my class probably don't, and our professor hasn't mentioned them yet in the course. Is the proof incorrect if just the $\lim$ is given, but not the $\lim \sup$? (Obviously, if the $\lim$ exists, then $\lim \sup = \lim \inf = \lim$.)

Comment: Yes, with this particular argument you cannot write $\lim$ since at that point you don't know yet whether it exists.

Comment: I will add an alternative argument without $\limsup$.

Comment: thank you. I appreciate that.